# HaxeFlixel, icon turns into a Black square

Tags: svg, icons, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to change my game's icon for Windows, using SVG format.

I use this command line in the `project.xml`, but the icon is still black:

```
<icon path="icon.svg"></icon>
```

Comment: Is the svg icon in the same folder as your project.xml file?

Comment: Yes, there are in the same folder